# Possible to show only traceback in Django error response?

Tags: python, django

When an error occurs in Django (specifically an HTTP 500 "Internal Server Error"), I get an error dump that looks like the following, which I've truncated for brevity:

```
ValueError at <request_url>
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'jbishop'

Request Method: POST
Request URL: <request_url>
Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Executable: <path_to_python>
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path: [ ... several lines of output ...]
Server time: Fri, 15 May 2020 14:11:14 +0000
Installed Applications:
['base.apps.BaseConfig',
 'web.apps.WebConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'qinspect.middleware.QueryInspectMiddleware']


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<some_path_here>", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  ... continues ...
```

I **never** care about all those random variables shown immediately below the first two lines that indicate what error occurred. I **always** care about the traceback, so I can pinpoint where in my code the problem is occurring.

Does Django provide capability to modify the error response in some way so I can show just the error and the traceback? It drives me crazy that I have to scroll many lines down to get to what's important.

Comment: It's not that these are not important, they are made for ease in debugging, they help to get common errors and information out. It does not take much effort scrolling to the bottom + most terminals automatically show the bottom thus no need to scroll down. Still I agree with you for these small errors we should have this capability we can use exception handling (try-except blocks).

Comment: I tried to find which template to override but I couldn't find it, so I'm also interested in the answer. 
Meanwhile, to get only the traceback, why don't you look at the console output from the server, instead of the HTML response?

Comment: These errors usually occur for me in an AJAX call, and my configuration doesn't output those errors to the console window. I generally view these errors in the Chrome developer tools window, which I have sized fairly small to keep out of the way. I realize I could make the window larger to see more of the output, but I'd like to override the output if possible to boil things down to just what I want to see.